possibility concerning a circle graph
Suppose we have $n$ layers ($n>3$). For each layer, there are $m$ sites. We need to pick $p$ sites ($p < m/2$) from $m$ possible sites for each layer so that there is no duplicated site number picked up for every neighboring layer. What is the total number of possible combinations?
Note: the top and the bottom layers are also defined as neighboring layers.


Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Please edit to include your efforts.  I note that it might not even be possible...if, say, you have three "layers" each with $5$ sites and you seek to choose $2$ sites from each, it's impossible to avoid matches between layers.  $p<\frac m2$ isn't good enough.  $p≤\frac m3$ should do it.

@lulu: thanks. I just added $n>3$

$n > 3$ does not solve the problem. No matter how many layers there are, each picked site precludes two other sites from being picked, so the maximum number of sites that can be picked is $\left\lfloor \frac{nm}3\right\rfloor$. You need to pick $np$ sites, so if $p > \frac m3$, this will not be possible.
